Why is a server-side function called with google.script.run invoked twice, 10 seconds apart?
I have a script bound to a sheet. It needs to

prompt the user for some data
do some processing, which may take more than 10 seconds.

Seemed like a client-side HTML form was the way to go for 1 because the user needs to select from dynamically generated lists. I want the dialog in 1 to close right after Submit and the server-side processing to be done asynchronously.
Everything works fine unless step 2 takes more than 10 seconds. In that case, the server-side function processForm() gets invoked again, exactly 10 seconds after the first invocation. 
I simplified the code to the bare bones to isolate the issue. The form is now just a button, processForm() just sleeps for 15 seconds.
It seems that the client is making a second call if there's no response in 10 seconds, but I haven't found any documentation to that effect. And I confirmed that handleSubmit() is invoked only once.
Server-side code:
var ui;

function onOpen(e) {
  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('test', 'test')
    .addToUi();
}

function test() {
  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Input');
  ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Input');
}

// Function to process the form data. Called from HTML script
function processForm() {
  Logger.log('in processForm');
  Utilities.sleep(15000);      
  return;
}

Client-side code (Input.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleSubmit()">
      <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script>
      function handleSubmit() {
        console.log("handleSubmit invoked at:", new Date().toISOString());
        google.script.run.processForm(); // process the server-side code asynchronously, so this dialog can close right away
        google.script.host.close(); // Close the dialog 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


When I tested your showing script several times, unfortunately, I could not replicate It seems that the client is making a second call if there's no response in 10 seconds. I apologize for this situation. Can I ask you about the detailed steps for correctly replicating your current situation using your showing script?

@Tanaike Thanks for trying it! Did you run "test" a few times from the spreadsheet's Extensions->NC PO menu? Did the "hi" dialog pop up? Did you wait at least 10 seconds before closing it?

Thank you for replying. About Thanks for trying it! Did you run "test" a few times from the spreadsheet's Extensions->NC PO menu? Did the "hi" dialog pop up? Did you wait at least 10 seconds before closing it?, it's yes. But, I cannot confirm It seems that the client is making a second call if there's no response in 10 seconds. I apologize for this.

@Tanaike OK, that's good to know! Maybe there's something about my environment, and not the code that's causing this behavior.

Thank you for replying. For example, when you created a new Google Spreadsheet and copy and paste your showing script and test it again, what result will you obtain? If the same issue occurred, your comment might be correct.

@Boris nope! It happens to me too; rather arbitrarily, I must say (~one out of four times). 10s too, by the way. I've never noticed whether it has happened on my own scripts too.

In any case, the function is not actually executed twice. I don't know how it works, but I've set it to write some value in my spreadsheet and it does it only once, regardless of how many calls appear on the log.

@Tanaike Yes, I see the same behavior when the code is bound to a different sheet.

@user27425627 Thanks for trying it out! Good to know it's not just me. I haven't tried writing something to the spreadsheet, but I do know that it executed the code within the function twice. Something as simple as Logger.log

Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether this is your expected direction, for example, how about modifying google.script.run.processForm(); google.script.host.close(); to google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).processForm();?

@Tanaike This would mean waiting for processForm() to finish before closing the client-side dialog, right? I don't want that because that will be confusing to the user.

Thank you for replying. About This would mean waiting for processForm() to finish before closing the client-side dialog, right? I don't want that because that will be confusing to the user., I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

I don't want that because that will be confusing to the user... But does this fix the issue? If so, you can try both? google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).processForm();setTimeout(google.script.host.close, 100);

@TheMaster Thanks for the suggestion! Using withSuccessHandler does eliminate the second invocation, but leaves the first dialog up, as expected. Adding setTimeout closes the first dialog, but brings back the second invocation of processForm after 10 seconds.

Try adding a failureHandler along with success handler and see if that resolves the issue? .withFailureHandler(()=>{})

@TheMaster It does not :(

The browser console(F12) may provide some clues. I'd check what happens when it works and when the issue happens. But this maybe a wild goose chase. You might wanna create an issue in the issuetracker. See tag info page for links to tracker.

@TheMaster Nothing additional appears in the console. I guess creating an issue is the next step. Thanks again for the ideas!

Turns out it's not specifically the server-side dialog in step 2 that's causing the issue. It's just the fact that the processing takes more than 10 seconds.

Created issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/372736286

@user27425627 If you'd like to edit the community wiki answer to confirm the issue or add extra revelations on your testing or add a completely new answer, please do so.

This issue was reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/372736286
Consider adding a +1 to the tracker, if you want Google developers to prioritise this issue.
